# Elasticsearch 5.6 multi_match search with edge_ngram returning zero results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have documents like following in Elasticsearch:

```
{
  "_index" : "demo_index",
  "_type" : "doc",
  "_id" : "user_122",
  "_version" : 4,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "id" : 1520488,
    "doc_type" : "user",
    "user_email" : "neeraj@test.com",
    "user_first_name" : "Neeraj",
    "user_last_name" : "Goel"
  }
}
```

And following is the query which is returning zero results.

**Note:This is case is occuring only when the full name is bifurcated into *user_first_name* and *user_last_name* fields in the index.**

```
{
  "index": "demo_index",
  "type": "doc",
  "body": {
    "from": 0,
    "size": "200",
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "term": {
              "doc_type": "user"
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "user_status": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "multi_match": {
              "query": "neeraj goel",
              "operator": "AND",
              "fuzziness": "AUTO",
              "fields": [
                "user_first_name.edge_ngram",
                "user_last_name.edge_ngram"
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "should": {
          "prefix": {
            "user_first_name.sort": "neeraj goel"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sort": {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The edge_ngram settings used in index are:

```
{
  "edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
    "token_chars": [
      "letter"
    ],
    "min_gram": "2",
    "type": "edge_ngram",
    "max_gram": "8"
  }
}
```

Mappings:

```
{
  "user_first_name": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "edge_ngram": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer"
      },
      "ngram": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
      },
      "raw": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    },
    "analyzer": "standard"
  }
}
```

I am not able to figure what's wrong with my query because as mentioned above the query is working fine when there is no user_last_name in the document.

Can any one please help me out with this query.

Thanks.

Comment: data you have provided is not sufficient to reproduce the issue, please add more clarity what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

As your index setting and mapping is not complete and it's not clear what you want to achieve , **I added a example which works and near to your use case, what I understood and will change it once you add more data.**

**Index def with mapping and settings**

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer"
                },
                "ngram_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
                    "token_chars": [
                        "letter"
                    ],
                    "min_gram": "2",
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "max_gram": "8"
                },
                "ngram_tokenizer": {
                    "token_chars": [
                        "letter"
                    ],
                    "min_gram": "2",
                    "type": "ngram",
                    "max_gram": "8"
                }
            }
        },
        "index.max_ngram_diff": 10 // note this
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "user_first_name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "edge_ngram": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer"
                    },
                    "ngram": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
                    },
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "user_last_name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "edge_ngram": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer"
                    },
                    "ngram": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
                    },
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": "standard"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And add sample doc to index**

```
{
   "user_first_name" : "Neeraj",
   "user_last_name" : "Goel"
}
```

**And search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "neeraj goel",
                        "operator": "or", // note this
                        "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                        "fields": [
                            "user_first_name.edge_ngram",
                            "user_last_name.edge_ngram"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": {
                "prefix": {
                    "user_first_name.sort": "neeraj goel"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And search results**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "myindexedge",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0500396,
                "_source": {
                    "user_first_name": "Neeraj",
                    "user_last_name": "Goel"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Hi,  I am trying to update the index settings but getting error.

Index settings update query:

curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/myindex/_settings?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "index" : {
        "max_ngram_diff" : 10
    }
}
'

Error:

"root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "unknown setting [index.max_ngram_diff] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
      }
    ]

Comment: @NeelkanthKaushik, you need to close the index before updating the setting, use XPUT http:localhost:9200/<your-index>/_close for that and after that update the setting, open the index, ` XPUT http:localhost:9200/<your-index>/_open` and reindex your data again.

Comment: I deleted all the indices in my cluster and then tried to create a new index but still getting the same error;

{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.max_ngram_diff] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.max_ngram_diff] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},"status":400}

Comment: My ES version is 5.6.14

Comment: @NeelkanthKaushik its not related to ES version, can you show your complete request for creating the index with setting ?

Comment: @NeelkanthKaushik were u able to resolve the issue??